# Convert String to Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: actionscript-3, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to convert a string into a multi-dimensional array?

e.g.:

```
new Array(new Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), new
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), new 
    Array(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), new 
    Array(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1), new 
    Array(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1), new 
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1), new 
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1), new 
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1), new 
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), new 
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), new 
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1), new 
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1), new 
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1), new 
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1), new 
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1), new 
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1), new 
    Array(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1), new 
    Array(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1), new 
    Array(1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1), new 
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

It's a string, the words and the brackets are characters too, I want to convert this into a real Array.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: are you trying to do some kind of "eval" ?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to convert one of the textfield's text (where I insert the above array) into a multi-dimensional array. (the same array structure)

Comment: This seems terribly complicated, and weird, what are you "really" trying to do? :0

Comment: Input Text Field -> Multi Dimensional Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure there is a better way to write the regex, but here it goes, basically it removes the "new", replaces "Array(" with "[" and replaces ")" with "]". The resulting string is a valid JSON string which can be turned into an array with JSON.parse().

```
var str:String = "new Array(new Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), new\
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), new \
    Array(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), new \
    Array(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1), new \
    Array(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1), new \
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1), new \
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1), new \
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1), new \
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), new \
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), new \
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1), new \
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1), new \
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1), new \
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1), new \
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1), new \
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1), new \
    Array(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1), new \
    Array(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1), new \
    Array(1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1), new \
    Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))";

    var myPattern:RegExp = /new/g;  

    var json:String = str.replace(myPattern, " ");   
    myPattern = /Array\(/g;

    json = json.replace(myPattern, "[");

    myPattern = /\)/g;
    json = json.replace(myPattern, "]");

    var array:Array = JSON.parse(json) as Array;
```

Comment: My JSON (latest version) doesn't have parse function.

Comment: If you are using the Adobe libraries then use JSON.decode() JSON.parse is available in the flash player after version 11.